# PSQL loss of precision during cast real to text

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I try to cast 292286.4 (`real`) to `text`, it returns me '292286.406'.

```
update table_name set text_col = cast(real_col as text) where id = 1;
```

How could I get exact value?

Comment: Please, provide more information like Postgres version and result of query for related record. Because, it returns as it is expected here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b909e4edfa00812060c353e3117af810

Comment: 1) It looks like an increase in precision. 2) What is [extra_float_digits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-EXTRA-FLOAT-DIGITS) set to in postgresql.conf? You get that in `psqll` by doing `show extra_float_digits ;`.

Comment: PostgreSQL 11.13, extra_float_digits: 3

Comment: I don't have a Postgres 11 instance to test with. On your end in `psql` do , `set extra_float_digits = 0;` then `select '292286.4'::real::text;` to see what you get? Per here [Float](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT) the default for `extra_float_digits`  in version 11 should be 0.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to show how you know that `real_col` is 292286.4 and not actually 292286.406 already?